# 301 Direct from old site folders to new site structure

Tags: php, http-status-code-301

Thanks in advance.

I have redone my website with new folder structures

Old site structure:
www.domain.com/folder/file.aspx

New site structure:
www.domain.us/folder/file.php

Notice the new TLD. I have around 20 folders that I want to redirect. Is it possible to do this with one file or do I have to do a 301 for each individual folder from the old site to the new site? What is the best way to handle this?

Again,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Has any of the structure changed, and do you have any existing ReqriteRules? It would be best if 404s are caught before sending a 301.

Comment: You say the folder structures have changed, but in your example they're the same, only the TLD and extension have changed. Do you have specific examples of how the folders have changed? It's hard to answer your question without a more specific example in this case.

However, you should be able to do it all from a single .htaccess file in the root, though it may require a line for each folder.

Answer (score 1):

You should use mod_rewrite for that. Put this in the **.htaccess** file in the **public_html** folder of your FTP:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.aspx$ $1.php [L]
```

This should make sure that when someone is calling **Banana.aspx** they get to see **Banana.php**.

Answer (score 1):

The .htaccess file in the directory takes precedence over any .htaccess file in the parent directories. So, if you already have .htaccess file in each of your sub-directories then putting an .htaccess file in your root directory makes no sense.

Remove the .htaccess files from each of your sub-directories that you want to redirect and update the .htaccess file in your root folder. You probably need to put 20 rewrite rules like this. **Keep in mind that removing .htaccecss from sub-directories will remove all restrictions that you [might] have put on that folder.**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com
RewriteRule ^folder/file\.aspx$ http://domain.us/folder/file.php [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^folder2/file\.aspx$ http://domain.us/folder2/file.php [R=301,NC,L]
```

301 for permanent redirect, NC for No Case, L for Last rule to process if matches

**OR**

Update the .htaccess file in each directory that you want to redirect

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.aspx$ http://domain.us/folder/$1.php [R=301,NC,L]

#the following might also do; just test it out
#RedirectPermanent (.*)\.aspx$ http://domain.us/folder/$1.php
```

So,, depending on your situation, you pick one. I'd go with option one so that all redirects are in one place. You can always move the restrictions from subdirectories' .htaccess to root's .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

If you use 301 PHP header() redirect, then I'm afraid it can only be done one-by-one.

But if you use mod_rewrite to handle this for you, then this is a relevant source for you to have a look: http://www.gnc-web-creations.com/301-redirect.htm